# $\sqrt{m^2 - x^2} \leq x , m > 0$ the range for $x$ is?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$\sqrt{m^2 - x^2} \leq x $

$\sqrt{{m}^{2} - {x}^{2}} \geq 0$

$x \geq 0$

$\sqrt{m^2 - x^2} \leq x $

$m^2 - x^2 \leq x^2 $

$m^2 \leq 2x^2$

$\frac{m}{\sqrt 2} \leq x$

$\sqrt{{m}^{2} - {x}^{2}} \geq 0$

${m}^{2} \geq {x}^{2}$

$m > 0, x > 0$

$m \geq x$

$x \leq m$

$\frac{m}{\sqrt 2} \leq x \leq m$

is it right?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you would explain your answer as well.

Comment: The final answer is right. But should add more context: what is $m$, etc.

Comment: Think about it graphically: $\sqrt{m^2-x^2}$ represents a semicircle with radius $m$ centred  at the origin, and $x$ is a straight line through the origin with gradient 1. Their point of intersection is $(\frac{m}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{m}{\sqrt{2}})$

Comment: How to know that semicircle has equation $\sqrt{m^2 - x^2}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up to the sixth line $$m^2\le 2x^2,$$ all is well. But the seventh line doesn't necessarily follow from it without making additional assumptions about $x,$ which we're not allowed to make.

What follows is that $m/\sqrt 2\le |x|,$ and from this we have that $$x\ge \frac{m}{\sqrt 2},$$ or else that $$x\le -\frac{m}{\sqrt 2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $0<x<m^2$, tthe squaring we get

$$m^2-x^2 \ge x^2 \implies  0\le x \le m/\sqrt{2}$$